# error TS2304: Cannot find name 'ga'

Tags: angular, google-analytics

I am using Angular4 and trying to get analytics installed.
I followed this guide:

https://blog.thecodecampus.de/angular-2-include-google-analytics-event-tracking/

But when I try to build my project, I get the error:

> error TS2304: Cannot find name 'ga'.

I have checked my package.json and I have `"@types/google.analytics": "0.0.38",` installed in my **devDependencies**.
When I start typing I can see that intellisense knows it's a `UniversalAnalytics.ga` type, but I cannot get it to work.

I tried changing my code to this:

```
this.router.events.subscribe(event => {
  if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
    let ga: Function;
    ga('set', 'page', event.urlAfterRedirects);
    ga('send', 'pageview');
  }
});
```

It compiles, but in the console.log I get an error stating:

> Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: ga is not a function

If I change to this:

```
this.router.events.subscribe(event => {
  if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
    let ga: any;
    ga('set', 'page', event.urlAfterRedirects);
    ga('send', 'pageview');
  }
});
```

I get the same error.
Does anyone know why?

Here is the complete code:

```
import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewChecked, AfterViewInit } from "@angular/core";
import { ActivatedRoute, Params, Router, NavigationEnd } from "@angular/router";

import { ResultsService } from "./shared/results.service";
import { HeightService } from "./shared/height.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'bzRoot',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewChecked, AfterViewInit {
  constructor(
    private _activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
    private _resultsService: ResultsService,
    private _heightService: HeightService,
    public router: Router) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this._activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe((params: Params) => {
      // Only update the elq if it changes (remember: changing a parameter causes the page to refresh)
      var elq = params['elqid'];
      if (elq) {
        this._resultsService.elq = elq;
      }
    });
  }

  ngAfterViewChecked() {
    this._heightService.resize();
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    //this.router.events.subscribe(event => {
    //  if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
    //    let ga: Function;
    //    ga('set', 'page', event.urlAfterRedirects);
    //    ga('send', 'pageview');
    //  }
    //});
  }
}
```

Comment: npm i -D @types/google.analytics

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Somehow the  @types/google.analytics package seams to be broken.  Just add this to your code:

```
declare let ga: Function;
```

I'll update my blog post.

Comment: I found the answer btw, '(<any>window).ga' works. I found it in another directive

Comment: `declare let ga: (string, string, string) => void;` is better for TSLint

Answer (score 9):

You can add `google.analytics` to the types in your tsconfig.json

```
"types": [
  "node",
  "google.analytics",
],
```

..or you can remove the entire `types` property from the config to have it use all in @types.
Check the part on 'types' here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html

Comment: This should be the accepted answer ;-)

Answer (score 5):

I found an alternative to doing the declare. I modified my code to this:

```
this._router.events.subscribe(event => {
  if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
    (<any>window).ga('set', 'page', event.urlAfterRedirects);
    (<any>window).ga('send', 'pageview');
  }
});
```

And it worked.
I found this method in another directive.

Answer (score 3):

Also, you can avoid typescript type checks completely:

```
 window['ga']('set', 'page', event.urlAfterRedirects);
 window['ga']('send', 'pageview');
```

Answer (score 2):

I recently faced this issue and I solved adding the types definition package for google analytics [@types/google.analytics](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/google.analytics).

So if you need to handle some popular api that expose some global variable like (google analytics, lodash, jquery, etc..) look for the types definition on npmjs. if you don't find it, you can create your own [declaration file](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/introduction.html)